# std::find on vector of objects with overloaded == operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to use std::find on the following vector:

```
std::vector<LoopDetectorData *> Vec_loopDetectors;
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
const LoopDetectorData *searchFor = new LoopDetectorData( (*it).c_str(), "", vehicleName.c_str() );
std::vector<LoopDetectorData *>::iterator counter = std::find(Vec_loopDetectors.begin(), Vec_loopDetectors.end(), searchFor);
```

This is the definition of LoopDetectorData class with operator == overloading.

```
class LoopDetectorData
{
  public:
    char detectorName[20];
    char lane[20];
    char vehicleName[20];
    double entryTime;
    double leaveTime;
    double entrySpeed;
    double leaveSpeed;

    LoopDetectorData( const char *str1, const char *str2, const char *str3, double entryT=-1, double leaveT=-1, double entryS=-1, double leaveS=-1 )
    {
        strcpy(this->detectorName, str1);
        strcpy(this->lane, str2);
        strcpy(this->vehicleName, str3);

        this->entryTime = entryT;
        this->leaveTime = leaveT;

        this->entrySpeed = entryS;
        this->leaveSpeed = leaveS;
    }

    friend bool operator== (const LoopDetectorData &v1, const LoopDetectorData &v2);
};
```

It seems that std::find can not find an item even if the item exists in the vector.

Comment: You cannot overload operators for built-in types, which includes pointers.

Comment: Your `vector` contains `LoopDetectorData *`, so `std::find` is going to compare pointers for equality, and `searchFor` is never going to compare equal to any of the pointers already in the `vector`. In all likelihood, you should be using `std::vector<LoopDetectorData> Vec_loopDetectors;`

Comment: Since you just created `searchFor`, a pointer to it can't possibly be in the vector.

Comment: Thank you all. I got it. Why I received so many minus votes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find()` searches by value.  So it will compare pointers stored in your vector to the pointer which you just created to serve as search argument.  This is dommed to fail: you compare pointers and not the values of the object poitned to.

You shall use **[`std::find_if()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)** instead:

```
auto counter = std::find_if (Vec_loopDetectors.begin(),
                             Vec_loopDetectors.end(), 
                             [&searchFor](const LoopDetectorData *f)->bool
                               { return *f == *searchFor; }
                             );
```

find_if uses a predicate which is here an ad-hoc lambda function that compares the values pointed to by dereferencing the pointers.  If you're not comfortable with lambdas, you could use a function poitner instead.

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/Q25enH) of this alternative, with a comparison to you rinitial attempt.